# Java char to bytes and back is converted wrongly (UTF-8)

Tags: java, string, encoding

While programming I encountered a weird behavior of Strings that are converted to bytes and then back to Strings again. Some chars are converted wrongly, and therefore the `hashCode` of the String is also changed. The length of the Strings remain the same.
The problem seems to occur with chars from 55296 - 57343 (U+D800 to U+DFFF). Other chars work fine. Is it because they are surrogates?

```java
String string = new String(new char[] { 56000 });
System.out.println((int)string.charAt(0));
System.out.println((int)new String(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).charAt(0));
```

The console output is:

```java
56000
63
```

What is going on here? Is this a java bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The hashCode of a String with length 1 is nothing else than the char of it itself. I replaced it in the question.

Comment: Why are you doing these conversions at all? String is not a container for binary data. Use a byte array for everything.

Comment: Encryption / decryption that has to be using String. If the string is malformed, i will now throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because these values are not characters but surrogates. Two of these values form a surrogate pair that in turn represents one character. If you have just one low or high surrogate value this is an invalid encoding and not a character.

Since this is an invalid encoding, it is replaced by a "?" character when you convert it to UTF-8.

You can read more about it for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Comment: But why is `string.getBytes(UTF_8)` a single byte array? Where does the other one go?

Comment: Interesting behavior! So java expects a surrogate to have a succeeding character, otherwise it is encoded wrongly.